# angular 2 - kendo datepicker max and min doesnt work

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

Kendo datepicker doesn't work. Can anyone tell me where I made mistake? Min date suppose to be today's date. Here is sample code: 
**app.html**

```
<div [class]="datePickerClass">
    <kendo-datepicker class="kendo-datepicker" 
                        id="startDate"
                        [ngModel]="_startValue"
                        [min]="min"
                        [max]="max"
                        (ngModelChange)="startValueChanged($event)"
                        [format]="formatDisplay"></kendo-datepicker>
</div>
<div [class]="datePickerClass">
    <kendo-datepicker class="kendo-datepicker" 
                        id="endDate"
                        [ngModel]="_endValue"
                        [min]="min"
                        [max]="max"
                        (ngModelChange)="endValueChanged($event)"
                        [format]="'d MMM yyyy'"></kendo-datepicker>
</div>
<ng-content>
</ng-content>
```

**app.ts**

```js
public min = new Date();
public max: Date = new Date(2017, 1, 1);
```

**File structure**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem recently try the following :

```
private today = new Date();
public min: Date = new Date(this.today.getFullYear(), this.today.getMonth(), this.today.getDate());
```

this worked for me, also change the "max" to some date after 11/7/2017  :)